# Display MapView with other widgets together in android Studio

Tags: android

Please I need help, I've been trying to figure this thing out, I want to display a MapView, a button, and two text views. I have done all that I can, and have watch lots of tutorials and still didn't figure it out, what I want is not what is displaying on the screen, the map shows up pretty fine, but the other widgets don't show up, and a search bar appears on top of the map that I don't know how to get rid off. And am apologizing in advance for my bad code writing, I am not an expert. PLEASE HELP. THANK YOU.

## Layout

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/White"
    android:id="@+id/relTest">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:background="@color/White">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:id="@+id/map_container">

            <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/map" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/info_tab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_full_screen_black_24dp"
                android:background="@color/White"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/btn_full_screen_map"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/online_offline_btn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="#0033cc"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Go Online"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/score_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@color/green1"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Player Score"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rating_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@color/green1"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Rating"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>



    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>```


#MapActivity 


public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        View.OnClickListener,
        GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener {

    //firestore access for cloud storage
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

    private static final String TAG = "MapActivity";
    private static final int ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;
    private static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
    private static final String COURSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
    private boolean mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;
    private static final float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 17f;

    private WorkerLocation mUserLocation;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    private boolean markerPinned;


    //for adding a custom marker
    private BitmapDescriptor bitmapDescriptorFromVector(Context context, int vectorResId) {

        Drawable vectorDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, vectorResId);
        vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);
        return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    //vars
    private FirebaseFirestore mDb;
    private GoogleMap map;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        //getLocationPermission();
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        mDb = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        markerPinned = false;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
            String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
                    "MY Channel",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).createNotificationChannel(channel);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = null;

            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setContentTitle("")
                    .setContentText("").build();

        }

        initMap();

    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady: map is ready here");
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Map is ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        if (mMap.getUiSettings().isMapToolbarEnabled()) {
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
        }

        getDeviceLocation();

    }

    private void getLastKnownLocation() {
        Log.d(TAG, "getLastKnownLocation: called.");


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<android.location.Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<android.location.Location> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Location location = task.getResult();
                    GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                    mUserLocation.setGeoPoint(geoPoint);
                    mUserLocation.setTimeStamp(null);

                    saveUserLocation();
                    startLocationService();

                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void getUserDetails(){

        if(mUserLocation == null){
            mUserLocation = new WorkerLocation();
            DocumentReference userRef = mDb.collection("User locations")
                    .document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid());

            userRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: successfully set the user client.");
                        User user = task.getResult().toObject(User.class);
                        mUserLocation.setUser(user);
                        ((UserClient)getApplicationContext()).setUser(user);
                        getLastKnownLocation();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else{
            getLastKnownLocation();
        }

    }


    private void saveUserLocation(){

        if(mUserLocation != null){
            DocumentReference locationRef = mDb.collection("User location")
                    .document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid());

            locationRef.set(mUserLocation).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Log.d(TAG, "saveUserLocation: \ninserted user location into database." +
                                "\n latitude: " + mUserLocation.getGeoPoint().getLatitude() +
                                "\n longitude: " + mUserLocation.getGeoPoint().getLongitude());
                    }

                }
            });

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(checkMapServices()){
            if(mLocationPermissionGranted){

                getUserDetails();
            }
            else{
                getLocationPermission();
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkMapServices(){
        if(isServicesOk()){
            if(isMapsEnabled()){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isMapsEnabled(){
        final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

        if ( !manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
            buildAlertMessageNoGps();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("This application requires GPS to work properly, do you want to enable it?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                        Intent enableGpsIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivityForResult(enableGpsIntent, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ENABLE_GPS);
                    }
                });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }


    public boolean isServicesOk() {
        Log.d(TAG, "isServicesOk: checking google services version");

        int available = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(MapActivity.this);

        if (available == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            //everything is ok and the user can make a map request
            Log.d(TAG, "isServicesOk: Google play services is working");
            return true;
        } else if (GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isUserResolvableError(available)) {
            //an error occured but we can resolve it
            Log.d(TAG, "isServicesOk: an error occured but we can fix it");

            Dialog dialog = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(MapActivity.this, available, ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST);
            dialog.show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You can't make map request", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return false;
    }


    private void getDeviceLocation() {
        Log.d(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: getting the device current location");

        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        try {
            if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {// check first to see if the permission is granted
                Task<Location> location = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
                location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: Location found");
                            Location currentLocation = task.getResult();
                            //move camera to current location on map
                            moveCamera(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM, "My location");
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: current location null");
                            Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "Could not get current location, make sure location is enagbled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: SecurityException:" + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    private void moveCamera(LatLng latlng, float zoom, String title) {
        Log.d(TAG, "moveCamera: moving camera to current latitude:" + latlng.latitude + " longitude" + latlng.longitude);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng, zoom));
        //create a marker to drop pin at the location
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().position(latlng);

        if (markerPinned) {
            mMap.addMarker(options.position(latlng)).setIcon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.user));
        } else {
            initMap();
            mMap.addMarker(options).setIcon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.user));
            markerPinned = true;
        }

    }


    private void initMap() {// for initializing the map
        Log.d(TAG, "initMap: initializing map");
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapActivity.this);


    }

    private void getLocationPermission() {
        String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(), FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(), COURSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
                getUserDetails();
                initMap();// if the location permission is granted
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "getLocationPermission: Location permission failed");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, LOCATION_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
            }

        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "getLocationPermission: Location permission failed");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, LOCATION_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        mLocationPermissionGranted = false;

        switch (requestCode) {
            case LOCATION_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {// that means some kind of permission was granted
                    for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
                        if (grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
                            Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermission: permission request failed");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermission: permission granted");
                    mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
                    //initialize our map
                    initMap();

                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: called.");
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ENABLE_GPS: {
                if(mLocationPermissionGranted){
                    getUserDetails();
                }
                else{
                    getLocationPermission();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private void startLocationService() {
        Log.d(TAG, "startLocationService: Start of location service method");

        if (!isLocationServiceRunning()) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(MapActivity.this, LocationService.class);
            this.startService(serviceIntent);

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

                MapActivity.this.startForegroundService(serviceIntent);

            } else {
                startService(serviceIntent);
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isLocationServiceRunning() {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if ("com.example.zts.services.LocationService".equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                Log.d(TAG, "isLocationServiceRunning: location service is already running.");
                return true;
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "isLocationServiceRunning: location service is not running.");
        return false;
    }

}

[![what I want when I run the application][1]][1]


[![what shows up when I run the app on the emulator][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTImR.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/evKfW.jpg
````

Answer (score 0):

Can not create entire layout but i below one is the layout which i created to customized my mapview design :

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          tools:context=".MapsActivity"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/white_border"
    android:id="@+id/relLayout1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/ic_magnify"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_magnify"/>

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ic_magnify"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:id="@+id/input_search"
        android:background="@null"
        android:hint="Enter Address, City or Zip Code"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"/>


</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/relLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:id="@+id/ic_gps"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_gps"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relLayout1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:id="@+id/place_info"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_info"/>
```

drawable/white_boarder.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#fff"/>
        <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

And at last if you want to disable defult widget of map you can do with getUiSettings().

```
 yourMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thank you for the trouble, it didn't work, none of the widgets appeared other than the map itself, I think the mistake lies within my code, I've messed it up so much that I only got my self confused.